# Error when referring to a list in Scheme, named using the `define` function

Tags: function, syntax, scheme, quote, function-call

I have named a list in Scheme using `define`. I've tried

```
(define aList (list 0 16 19))

(list-ref ‘(aList) 1)
```

But it says "error: `aList` is not a function". Why? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We reference a name by simply using it, in Scheme.

```
(define aList (list 0 16 19))

(list-ref aList 1)
```

should work.

Enclosing a name in parentheses means calling its value *as a function*. And the list `(list 0 16 19)` is *not* a function.

The quote `'` would normally have prevented this, which would lead to a different error message (try `(list-ref '(aList) 1)`), but you've used a different character there, `‘`, which has no special meaning in Scheme.

By the way, `define` is not a function in Scheme, but a macro<sup>(*)</sup>. Functions have their arguments evaluated before even starting their work, but here we want to *define* the value to which the name `aList` will refer from now on. This means it still has no value when the whole `define` "form" (i.e. parenthesized expression) is called, so if it were a function this would lead to a circularity.

As a macro, `define` gets to refer to the *name* itself, not the name's *value*. It *defines* its value, not *references* it (i.e. it *puts* the value there, not gets it *from* there).

<sup>(*)</sup> (now, it might be not a macro but a special operator, but from the language user's perspective it's the same thing; the difference is only seen from the implementer's point of view)